# What is the reason behind uncommitted work pending issue in the callout?

Tags: apex, managed-package, salesforcedx, scratch-org, calloutexception

I am getting uncommitted work pending issue in my test class but `Limits.getDMLStatements()` says there are **0 DML** performed before and after callout. What else could cause this issue?

> Code is running in Batch context inside `execute` method

```
try {
    System.debug(Limits.getDMLStatements()); //log: 0
    restclient.makeCallout(somedata);
}
catch(Exception ex){
   System.debug(Limits.getDMLStatements()); //log: 0
   System.debug(ex.getMessage()); //log: uncommitted work pending 
}
```

NOTE: I am getting this issue in my packaging org but scratch org test are passing.

Answer (score 5):

Database.executeBatch method modifies the state of the database(Creates an Apex Job record), so for purposes of callouts, count as a DML operation.

This is the reason you are getting `uncommitted work pending issue in the callout` exception.

As a workaround, you can directly call the execute method of batch class in a test context

**Example**

```
if(Test.isRunningTest()) {
    batchInstance.execute(null, listOfRecords);
} else {
    Database.executeBatch(batchInstance, 10);   
}
```